# Helm - How to change default selection while renaming?

Tags: helm, dired, helm-sources, helm-selection

I have a  dired buffer with two files

```
foo.py
foo_bar.py
```

Now to rename `foo.py` to `bar.py`, if  i goto `foo.py`,  press `R` and type `bar.py`, helm selection  will be like  this

[image]

Here helm is selecting  the top match  from the available file names.

How can i make helm to select the  user typed value as the default choice?

Comment: helm prefers exiting matches, I think this feature is implemented in the function `helm-comp-read--move-to-first-real-candidate`, which will be called in `'helm-after-update-hook`, you can change (advice) that function definition to disable this feature just for `R` in `dired` mode.

Comment: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/376